# Serial Com from PC VB2015 to 8051. PS sends 8Data and 1 stop bit. 8051 can rec 10bits, 1start 8data 1stop. Can the PC VB2015 send the 10bits?

Tags: microcontroller

The Intel 8051 supports four Serial Modes of operation. Mode 0 8-bits, baud rate is 1/12 the oscillator frequency. This won't work because VB2015 can not support that BAUD rate. Mode 1 10bits, 1start 8data 1 stop. VB does not support this. Mode 2 11bits 1start 8data 9thdata bit programmable 1stop bit. VB2015 does not support. Mode 3 basically the same as Mode 2.
What do you recommend I do to support serial communications between my Windows 10 PC running Visual Basic 2015 to the Intel 8751 microcontroller?

Comment: What is the reason for you to stick to mode 0 or 8bit? It sounds more like you have 1 start, 1 stop, 6bits data configuration (or similar) in 8051. I have not seen no-start-bit operation using UART.

Comment: Jay: Thank you for your comment and assistance. The 8051 Mode 0 supports 8 Data bits transfer. Visual Basic 2015 Serial Port tool enables the selection of 8 data bits, no start bit but when I attempt to select "None" (which is a option in the property drop down of the Stop Bit property) I receive an error message Enum value was out of legal range. Parameter name: StopBits. Strange as the None option is presented as an option.

Comment: Glenn, Look at this [RS232 (UART ASYNC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rs232_oscilloscope_trace.svg) waveform. Without a start bit, receiver cannot synchronize the data bits. No UART synchronize data bits from the stop bit. The start bit is a "Preamble" to synchronize transmission timing between two (or multiple) nodes. Meantime, I am curious, is there a reason why you need to use data bits (8 bits) only mode? I am not clear what you want to accomplish. We may be able to provide a better answer with more elaborated descriptions from you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about what VB supports.

Standard UART communication **is** 10 bit frames, divided into 1 start bit, 8 data bits and one stop bit - commonly called by name "8N1", where the N means no parity bit is used.

The baud rate support is defined by your hardware. Motherboard embedded serial ports typically support only standard baud rates up to 115200, but can also be set to any rate. USB serial ports support goes at least up to 3 Mbits and even beyond, and can many of them also support arbitrary non-standard baud rates.

Comment: It might help the OP to say that a standard UART provides the start and stop bits - the user only has to supply the eight data bits.

Comment: Justme, thank you for your comment and support. I understand your reply and realize the common functionality of a standard UART. My issue is that the 8051 Mode 0 supports 8 Data bits transfer. Visual Basic 2015 Serial Port tool enables the selection of 8 data bits, no start bit but when I attempt to select "None" (which is a option in the property drop down of the Stop Bit property) I receive an error message Enum value was out of legal range. Parameter name: StopBits. Strange as the None option is presented as an option.

Comment: You need a start bit and from the PC there is a start bit. It is just not mentioned as there is no need to mention it. I don't understand why your serial port tool allows selecting none for stop bit as it is invalid and you need a stop bit too.